# Has anybody integrated Sitecore to Saleforce Chatter?

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

Has anybody integrated Sitecore to Saleforce Chatter?

What is the better way to do that?

I have tried different ways including the DeveloperForce.Chatter, Ajax and Java scripts, but the DeveloperForce.Chatter uses the async call which isn't supported by Sitecore. and Java scripts and Ajax call requires domains to be white listed in Sitecore with a HTTPS(but my site cannot go fully HTTPS).

I am able to establish connection between Salesforce and Sitecore and retrieve the contact from there. But no luck with the chatters so far.

At this point I don't want to start something like Apex and waste my time if it is not a good solution for Sitecore.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It worked well with the WebClient